# TOC doesn't show the right page if I use setcounter

Tags: table-of-contents

In my article, I use two parts. In each one there are several sections. I would like the sections to be numbered from 1 in each part. 
I can't achieve it.
So I found on the web that using `\setcounter{0}` was the solution. It was but, now, the table of contents refers only to the pages of the first section. How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to [Tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). Add a minimal MWE, please.

Comment: Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: With `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{bla}

\newpage
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{blub}

\end{document} 
` I get the correct pages in the toc.

Comment: Do you mean \setcounter{page}{1}?   Also, you might want to use \def\thepage{\thepart.arabic{page}}